# Is the function recursive or r.e. with index?

Tags: recursion, set, enumerable

`S = {i | A ⊆ range( φi) }` where `A` is a set of all odd (or even) natural numbers and `φi` is function with index `i` which returns `A`.

How can I prove, that set `S` is recursive (or r.e., recursively enumerable) in every index?

Comment: I guess by r.e. you mean recursively enumberable, this should be written out. And it's unclear what you mean by the index of the function.